# Linking a href to an anchor in another HTML doc and centering it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner in web development and I'm try to build a portfolio but I'm encountering a little problem with my coding.

I want to link an href tag to a `<div id>` but in another `<html>`. 
Another issue is that I would like it to be center to the window.

This is an example:

INDEX.html

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="features.html#Spread5">
        <img src="i/Thumbnail_13.png" width="200"/> 
        <h5 class="slug">Departments</h5>
        <p>Muscle Fitness Hers</p>
    </a>
```

FEATURES.html

```
<div class="thumbnailspread" id="Spread5">
        <img src="i/Spread_5.png" width="420"/> 
        <h5 class="slug">Departments</h5>
        <p>Natural Health Magazine</p>
    </div>
```

The reason i want it to be centered is because I have a navigation toolbar that sticks to the top when you scroll down a certain amount (using a script i found online). 
So every time I click on the `<href>` the nav covers it on the next page.

Trying  to make it work with multiple divs in 4 different htmls
So it cant be too specific like this example:

```
function goToAnchor() {
window.location = "#center";
}
```

so, maybe I should use:

```
 window.location.href = "#"+anchor;
```

but I'm not sure if that is the right solution.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by `center on the window`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to be on center?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your current HTML in a div and center the link.

```
<div class="container">
  <a class="thumbnail" href="features.html#Spread5">...</a>
</div>
```

In your css file

```
.thumbnail {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d14saufr/1)